# Sorting on a single Enum

Tags: c#

```
public class SortComparer : IComparer<Test>
{
    public int Compare(Test x, Test y)
    {
       if (x.Sort == y.Sort)
            return 0;
        if (x.Sort != Sort.First && y.Sort == Sort.First)
            return -1;

        return 1;
    }
}

public enum Sort
{
    First,
    Third,
    Second,

}
public class Test
{
    public Sort Sort { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IList<Test> tests = new List<Test>();
        tests.Add(new Test { Sort = Sort.Second });
        tests.Add(new Test { Sort = Sort.Second });
        tests.Add(new Test { Sort = Sort.Third });
        tests.Add(new Test { Sort = Sort.Second });
        tests.Add(new Test { Sort = Sort.Third });
        tests.Add(new Test { Sort = Sort.First });
        tests.Add(new Test { Sort = Sort.First });

        IList<Test> ordered = tests.OrderBy(x => x, new SortComparer()).ToList();
    }
}
```

This is what I've tried so far. I am trying to get all the objects with the Sort enum value of `First` to the top of the list. The rest of the items I want to leave as is. Am I on the right path can anyone help me solve the rest of this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: That will not work, because the order of the remaining items is not guaranteed to remain the same. You would have to store the original index somewhere, and order by your sort comparer first, and the original index second. Also, if the two items are the same, you should return `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without ordering, you can do that using `Where` and `Concat`:

```
IList<Test> ordered = tests
            .Where(x => x.Sort == Sort.First)
            .Concat(tests.Where(x => x.Sort != Sort.First)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

"Compare" doesn't ensure to preserve original order. So you have to implement your own sort process if you want to keep other items than "First" ones on current position.

This is an simple, very naive, form of kinda sort :

```
// Initialization of "tests", class definition, etc.

List<Test> result = tests.Where(x => x.Sort == Sort.First ).ToList();       
var others = tests.Where(x => x.Sort != Sort.First);                
result.AddRange(others);
```

results should contains the expected list.

Comment: +1, I have removed unnecessary `ToList` calls to improve performance. You may revert it back if you want. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this comparer:

```
    public class SortComparer : IComparer<Test>
    {
        public int Compare(Test x, Test y)
        {
            if (x.Sort == y.Sort) {
                return 0;
            }
            if (x.Sort == Sort.First){
                return -1;
            }
            if (x.Sort == Sort.Second && y.Sort==Sort.First){
                return 1;
            }
            if (x.Sort == Sort.Second && y.Sort==Sort.Third){
                return -1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
```